# Searching an array list for an item, then printing out something

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, break

I have been working on an exercise summarized as follows:

> Write a program to store details of food items in a single array by using inheritance and polymorphism. Example, details of pizzas(item number, size, base), softdrinks(...)...

I have modeled everything, created my base class and derived classes.

Everything works fine except for one thing: when the user chooses to delete an item, I am supposed to output the string "Not found" if the item number is not found. My array list has each food item object (the subclasses) as elements. Here is my code for deleting an item from the array:

```
System.out.println("Enter the menu item number");
String num = input.next();

for(int j=0; j<menuItems.size();j++)    //menuItems is my arraylist
    { if((menuItems.get(j).getItemNumber().equals(num)))  //getItemNumber is a method in the derived class
      menuItems.remove(j);
    }
 System.out.println("Done");
 break; //for the switch statement
```

I am supposed to output "Not found" instead of "Done" if the item is not found in the array list. My initial attempt was as follows:

```
if(!menuItems.get(j).getItemNumber().contains(num))
    System.out.println("Not found");
else
    //the code above
```

This did not work because it is within the for-loop and the if-statement will check the array list even after the item has been removed. So, it will still evaluate to `true`.

Could someone please help me with this?

UPDATE:
I solved the problem as follows

```
           int found=0; // element not found found =0 else 1

              for(j=0; j<menuItems.size();j++)
              {

                 if((menuItems.get(j).getItemNumber().equals(num)))
                 {
                     menuItems.remove(j);
                     System.out.println("Done");
                     found+=1;
                 }

              }
             if (found ==0)
                {
                  System.out.println("Not found");
                }

           break;  //for the switch statement
```

Comment: what type does menuItems contain? What does getItemNumber return?

Comment: menuItems contain a class type - Food. And getItemNumber returns a String @vefthym

Comment: can you please post the whole switch statement? and fix indenting please

Comment: your solution should not work differently to the answers suggested. But since it worked for you, check why our suggestions did not, just for your better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it something like this

```
boolean found = false;

for(int j=0; j<menuItems.size();j++){ 
    if((menuItems.get(j).getItemNumber().equals(num))){
        menuItems.remove(j);
        found = true;
        break;
      }
    }

if(found){
    System.out.println("Done");
} else {
    System.out.println("Not found");
}
```

If you didn't manage to remove the item, then it wasn't there.

Comment: That didn't work. I am getting the output "Done" even if the item is not in the arraylist

Comment: You would need to debug through your code to work out what the error is in that case. found is initalised as 'false' so it will only print "Done" if something sets it to true. The only thing that could set it to true would be removing an item from the list.

Comment: I fixed the issue using a similar approach. Please see my edited post on how I managed to fix it. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you find and remove the element, break the switch (`plates` is just a random label):

```
plates: switch (smth) { //whatever you use here (not provided in the post)
...
  for(int j=0; j<menuItems.size();j++) {   //menuItems is my arraylist     
    if(menuItems.get(j).getItemNumber().equals(num)) {  //getItemNumber is a method in the derived class
      menuItems.remove(j);        
      System.out.println("Done!");
      break plates; //for the switch statement
    }      
  }      
  System.out.println("Not found!");      
  break; //for the switch statement (that you did not provide)
  ...
} //end of switch (if num is found, you continue from here)
```

Comment: With your code, I get an error message: unreachable statement

Comment: @John I guess because of the switch statement, that is not provided in your post.

Comment: Looks like someone doesn't like the 'found' boolean solution, we may never know why.

Comment: @vefthym thanks for the effort. But that still didn't work. It prints out "Done" even if the  item is not in the list

Comment: @John ok, so, instead of "Done!", print `num` and `menuItems.get(j).getItemNumber()` for debugging. They are equal, so you either add an element that you did not wish to add, or you changed `num` into a value that you did not wish. It means that there is an error somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @vefthym Please check my edited post to see how I fixed this issue. Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

I think maybe you can look at [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), then you can write your code like:

```
  HashMap<String, Food> = new Hashmap<>();

    String num = input.next();
    final Food temp = MyMap.get(num)

    if(temp == null)
    {
       //not found
    }
    else
    {
       //found
    }
```

Comment: Do you know of any other alternative method?

Comment: Sure i can use your ArrayList too. But IMHO you not use the most suited data structure in your program. If each "ItemNumber" is unique it's better to use some data structure with ordering and unique entry.